# How do you make a Get request to api with Bearer token and use the response data with C# (Windows Server)?

Tags: c#, windows, api, get, bearer-token

I need to receive data from an API via C# on a windows server. I have been able to receive my access token with the help of Luis Quintanilla's Spotify code https://gist.github.com/lqdev/5e82a5c856fcf0818e0b5e002deb0c28.

One thing I can't figure out is how to use this token in a Get Request using a Bearer token header. This is what I have so far.

```
Console.WriteLine("Token API");
AccessToken token = GetToken().Result;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Access Token: {0}", token.access_token));

        
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.access_token);

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> requestData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        requestData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));

        FormUrlEncodedContent requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);

        var request =  client.GetAsync("https://theapiendpoint.com", requestBody);
        // var response = request;
        var response = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(response);
```

I'm C# illiterate and the above produces some errors, specifically around the GetAsync request. I don't think I can add a header via the body like above. It is also erroring out on the request.Content piece. So how would one make this type of call and use the returned data? Is it "better" to make an async function and use the return? If so how do you pass the token down to said function? Again I'm VERY new to C# please be gentle. My Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this should be a POST instead of a GET. Get request with bodies are not recommended. Did you mean `var request = client.PostAsync(...`?

Comment: No, the API endpoint is expecting GET.  The have a post man set up the code its spits out is deprecated. 

var client = new RestClient("");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("ApiMsgSignature", "{{signature}}");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

Comment: Does PostAsync work with GET endpoints?

Comment: No, a get endpoint should only receive get requests.

Answer (score 0):

**NET Core and .NET 5+**

The second parameter of `client.GetAsync` is not the request body: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-6.0

You can send a GET request with a body (which doesn't seem normal) using `client.SendAsync`. You build your `HttpRequestMessage` first.

```
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> requestData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    requestData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://theapiendpoint.com"),
        Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData)
    };

    var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Also check what version of .NET you are using. There are different reccommended ways to new `HTTPClient`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/httpclient-guidelines

Edit:

Last 3 lines as Non-Async:

```
var responseMessage = client.Send(request);
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var responseString = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Hrrrm my original code isnt in an async function. If I wanted to separate things into their own async function what would that look like? and how would I go about sending the token down to that function?

Comment: If you are asking about passing parameters to a method, then a new question would be better.

Comment: Ok, if I change the lines to none async lines I get this error. "'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'Send' and no accessible extension method 'Send' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Im guessing this is a dotnet version issue, but im not sure how to check this via visual studio.

Comment: Yes it is a version issue. I would recommend trying to install .NET 6 and changing the version of your project. The version can be changed in the properties of you project in VS. You can make this work in .net framework by doing this: `var responseMessage = client.SendAsync(request).Result;` for the send method. Note that when you use Result you are blocking the thread.